# how to enable a user to select a single row from data set and send that data row to backend for processing using R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

is it possible in shiny to display a dataset (table) to the user(frontend) and select a "single" row from that dataset to process in the backend.

scenario:

i am developing a simple human activity(sitting, running,walking etc) recognition using sensor data app in R using UCI dataset "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Human+Activity+Recognition+Using+Smartphones"
.I will be training a certain classification model say naive bayes using dataset and then out of that dataset I want to give my trained model a single row of that dataset and find(recognize) to what class of activity that row belongs. Each row consists of values for various attributes of sensors for a particular instance.

I'll be developing it as a user interactive app "therefore using shiny" and want my entire dataset to be visible in front end(csv form) along with some option (say checkbox) to select a single row and provide my model in the backend that row to process.

I know this may not appear to be very interactive app but I want to "control from frontend" which row gets processed so that I could predict activity for that particular sensor data.Is it possible somehow??

note:from dataset(visible in frontend) I mean only that csv file which contains some 560 attributes, I have no interest in recognizing person(i.e 1-30)I just want activity.

Comment: hello you can try this to select row with `DT` http://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely possible. As @s.brunel mentions, it is made exceptionally easy by the `DT` package.

Below is a toy example where we run the rows that are clicked through the model.

```
library("shiny")
library("dplyr")
library("DT")
library("rpart")

set.seed(1)

# set an id variable
iris <- iris %>% mutate(id = row_number())

# select a training set
train_iris <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  sample_frac(0.75)

# select the testing rows
test_iris  <- anti_join(iris, train_iris, by = 'id')

# build the model
fit <- rpart(Species ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data = test_iris)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput('unscored'),
  DT::dataTableOutput('scored')
  )

server <- function(input, output) {

  # display the data that is available to be scored
  output$unscored <- DT::renderDataTable(test_iris)

  scored_data <- reactive({
    # make sure there are rows to score
    shiny::validate(
      need(length(input$unscored_rows_selected) > 0, "Select rows to score!")
    )

    score_dat <- test_iris[input$unscored_rows_selected, ]
    # return the data with the prediction
    data.table(
      score_dat,
      predicted = predict(fit, score_dat, type = "class")
    )
  })

  # display the scored data once processed by the model
  output$scored <- DT::renderDataTable(scored_data())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]